# Laravel how to rename sub controller directory, sub view directory and route?

Tags: laravel

I want to rename directory like:

- app/Http/Controllers/`SinglePage` => app/Http/Controllers/`Site`
- resources/views/`singlepage` => resources/views/`site`
- Route::resource('feature', '`SinglePage`\FeatureController') => Route::resource('feature', '`Site`\FeatureController')

Currently I spend time to rename them one by one and than go to rename related method also "return view('`SinglePage`.index') => return view('`Site`.index')".

Is it possible to rename them by CLI? or other way that faster?

Comment: phpstorm ide can come to rescue here.

Comment: What are you using as a text editor?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands

Comment: you can do from phpstrom

Comment: Now I am using PhpStorm 2017.1.4, how ?

Comment: @KakadaNeang right click on controller file => refactor =>rename and mark a checkboxes esspecially with `search for references`. This gonna do everything

Comment: @OleksiiDubeniuk thank you  so much for your help,

Comment: @KakadaNeang please accept the answer, if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

If you using PhpStorm just click on controller file=> refactor=>rename and mark a checkboxes esspecially with search for references. This gonna do everything.